# Input validation (Python)

Tags: python, validation, input

For input I need to have a string that contains both numbers and letters or only letters. Atm my code works with these conditions, but how can I add that input must not consist of punctuation marks?

```
nimi = input("...name: ")
while name.isalnum == True or name.isnumeric():
    name = input("...name: ")
```

Comment: The code you have won't give the answers you expect... you're missing parentheses. But note that once you fix this, it meets the requirement: if it's only letters and numbers or numbers, of course there's no punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use regex.

```
if re.match(r'^(?!\d+$)[\da-zA-Z]+$', pass):
```

Comment: or `while name.isalnum == True or name.isalpha():`

Answer (score -1):

As stated above, using `regex` is better. But the below condition will work for you. Use [string.punctuation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.punctuation) to take count of all the punctuations.

```
import string
while(name.isalnum() or name.isalpha()) and not any(i in string.punctuation for i in name):
```